# how to realize an alert that disappears after some seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I am struggling trying to find a way to create an alert that opens when you click a button and then should disappear after an amount of time that can be set as a parameter.

so far I have this:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("I will think later what to write here");
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item_add").click(function(){
        myFunction();
    });
});
</script>
```

How should I change the code to achieve the result?

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Browser alert box never auto disappear .it is not possible . you need to use custom jquery plugin suggested by `chris97ong`

Comment: You can't. Use [jQuery dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) instead. Alerts cannot be customized

Comment: Why not u just oopening any popupbox and call a close button method after a few seconds ?

Comment: mm ok I will try to take a look at jQuery dialog. Is it easy to use?

Comment: @user2692552  yes ..  you already use jquery in your page .. you just need to add jquery ui lib and css files .. and follow instruction mention in doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build the dialog yourself using HTML elements.

After this is done you should check `setTimeout()` that will allow you to perform a function after a preset period of time - e.g `visibility:hidden` your custom dialog.

```js
var hideTimeout = 1000; //how many ms to wait before hiding after displaying

function customAlert() {

  //display the box
  var customAlert = document.getElementById("custom-alert-1");
  customAlert.style.visibility = 'visible';

  //set up a timer to hide it, a.k.a a setTimeout()
  setTimeout(function() {
    customAlert.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }, hideTimeout)
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 32px;
}
.custom-alert {
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: enter;
  margin: 5% auto;
  padding: 12px 48px;
}
```

```html
<div id='custom-alert-1' class="custom-alert">Hello World</div>
<button onclick="customAlert()">Click to alert</button>
```

Since you are using jQuery you can substitute the `visibility` toggling for a `$('#custom-alert-1').fadeOut()` which provides a more streamlined show/hide effect.

---

If you are talking about the 'native' `alert()` then that won't ever work as JS does not have any access to it in any way apart from popping it open